# Proving $f(x)=\cos x\quad\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Suppose the function $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, and $f(r)=\cos r$ for every rational number $r$. Prove that $f (x) = \cos x$ for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}.$

I would very much appreciate a hint.

Comment: The rationals are dense in the reals and the cosine is continuous.

Comment: More broadly, if two continuous functions of a real variable agree on every rational, they must coincide.  Hint:  Suppose $f(x), g(x)$ are your function and that $f(a)\neq g(a)$ for some $a\in \mathbb R$.  Now consider a sequence of rationals which converges to $a$.

Comment: Thanks! Makes total sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\;x\;$ be any irrational number and prove that $\;f(x)=\cos x\;.$

Let $\;\left\{x_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ be the sequence of rational numbers defined as

$x_n=\dfrac{\lfloor 10^nx\rfloor}{10^n}\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

It results that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=x\;$ and, since $\;f(x)\;$ and $\;\cos x\;$ are functions continuous at the point $\;x\;,$ we get that

$f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\cos x_n=\cos x\;,\;$ hence

$f(x)=\cos x\;.$